# How to fill my textbox with the modal text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm facing a problem. I want to take the value of my modal textbox and on validation print it on my page text box but I'm getting this instead
`"[object Object]"`

This is my code :

```
@Html.LabelFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-sm-2">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "X_Y"})
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Dropdown1" })
</div>

@Html.LabelFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "col-sm-d col-sm-2 control-label" })
<div class="col-sm-2">
  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control"})
</div>
<div class="col-sm-2">
  @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(m => m.X.Y, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "Dropdown2" })
</div>
```

My modal :

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        Multiples
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" id="test" />
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal">
          Annuler
        </button>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">
          Valider
        </button>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And my scripts :

```
$(function() {
  $("#Dropdown1").change(function() {
    //Recupere la value de la liste
    selection = $(this).val();
    //Mettre la valeur du choix de liste.
    if (selection == 10) {
      //Affiche le modal
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
  });
});

var modalValue = $('#test');

$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#X_Y').val(modalValue);
});
```

Comment: `$('#X_Y').val(modalValue.val());` modalValue is the jquery object, you need to get the `val` from it.

Comment: Hell yeah ! This works so well thanks to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the value in a text box, you need to access the val() method of the input element.
So you should do:

```
var modalValue = $('#test');
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function() {
  $('#X_Y').val(modalValue.val());
});
```

Comment: Yeah thanks, but BenG already gave me the answer in comment :)

Comment: Would you know how i can make this work with more textboxes in the modal, for exemple, 3 text boxes and the 3 informations will be displayed in the page textbox, without any space.I have tried something but didn't worked. And it would look Like this : 1st text box would be 100 the next one would be % and the next would be XY and on the page textbox it will appear like this 100%XY

Comment: try concatenating the values of each textbox i.e `var text = modalValue1.val()+modalValue2.val()+modalValue3.val(); $('#X_Y').val(text)`

Comment: It works well, i did like this     var modalValue1 = $('#test') var modalValue2 = $('#test2')  var modalValue3 = $('#test3')  $('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#X_Y1').val(modalValue1.val()+modalValue2.val()+modalValue3.val());
    })